# Manually loading package from Vim-LaTeX in Vim (because auto detection is not always helpful)

Tags: vim, latex

### General question

How you can manually load a particular package from Vim-LaTeX in Vim and how it can be automated for every LaTeX file?

*I am not interested in copying relevant parts from scripts of particular package to `.vimrc` as a workaround.*

### Specific problem

This is just a supplementary part to explain how solving such problem may be useful.

#### Short reminder

In [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX 2ε](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) you can read that:

> A tilde ‘~’ character generates a space that cannot be enlarged and additionally
>   prohibits a line break.

In Polish we should not leave short conjunctions at the end of line. `~` is helpful here, but writing it after conjunctions is cumbersome (and spoils the typing flow, and you can just forget about it sometimes).

[Vim-LaTeX](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) (`vim-latexsuite` package in debian; *I am using version 20100129-2 in squeeze, just in case*) provides per package additional customization. For Polish texts we use package [polski](http://ctan.org/pkg/polski) in LaTeX and its Vim-LaTeX counterpart modifies space, so it automatically replaces space with tilde after short words.

#### Issue

For larger LaTeX documents splitting text between many files is a common practice. And here comes the problem with package detection in Vim-LaTeX. If I open the main `.tex` file (i.e. the one including other `.tex` files), where `\usepackage{polski}` is present, then space substitution works fine. It's not the file where you are writing much, thus it's not really useful here. But if I open any other `.tex` file (which is included by the main `.tex` file), which obviously does not have preamble (thereby there is no `\usepackage{polski}` in it), package detection fails, therefore space substitution is not working here.

#### Partial solution

I have figured out some partial flawed solution.

```
au FileType tex call Tex_pack_one('polski')
```

It's bad because it doesn't work if you open another `.tex` file in new window (via `:sp` or `:vs` for instance), even if this file have `\usepackage{polski}` (so it's a regression).

**Simple testing.** Go to insert mode and write `i i i`. You should see `i~i~i`. Open full LaTeX document (with preamble and `\usepackage{polski}`) in new window. Repeat the test there. Open third LaTeX document (w/o preamble) and repeat the test again.

#### Quote from my mail on vim-latex mailing list about using latex-master-file

*Sent: Sun, May 22, 2011 at 11:23 (GMT+02:00)*

I removed mentioned before `au FileType tex call
Tex_pack_one('polski')` line from `.vim.rc` to avoid any clashes and
added empty `main.tex.latexmain` file. From polski package PoV
situation is the same as with my partial solution. Only first opened
file works properly, another windows with `.tex` files do not.

I am starting to think that problem is in how package loading works
internally in vim-latex (as oriented mostly for rarely used menus
[correct me if I'm wrong], that should be extended only once)
preventing executing packages' scripts more than once. Also polski
package may have some bugs. I know Vim and can conveniently use its
editing powers, but I haven't learned Vim scripting language yet
(writing simple `.vimrc` doesn't require any special knowledge), thus
I cannot judge here and need help of advanced Vim users/programmers.

Comment: I've started a [thread](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=alpine.LNX.2.02.1105212123330.16261%40ybpnyubfg.ybpnyqbznva&forum_name=vim-latex-devel) at `vim-latex` mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Does adding this line to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` work?

```
call Tex_pack_one('polski')
```

Comment: No. `Error detected while processing /home/przemoc/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim: E117: Unknown function: Tex_pack_one`. But even if there would be no error, then it would be very similar to autocmd approach I've used, so I doubt there would be any improvement at all. See also a link in the comment to the question.

Comment: My mistake, that should have been: ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim  (I have edited my answer.)

Comment: As predicted, it gives same results as my autocmd approach.

Comment: Then it looks like something in the LaTeX plugin is trying to be too clever by setting a global "state" variable to prevent loading a script, or portions of a script that have already been loaded. I don't use the LaTeX stuff at all, but I suspect that a buffer local variable should have been used in this instance instead.

Comment: Don't know the details, but I'm also suspecting something is wrong somewhere, as I expressed it on `vim-latex` mailing list (linked previously) in response to Aditya's mail (with useful suggestion about `latex-master-file` I wasn't aware before). Maybe I should add my delibarations to the question here...